# Are drain-clearing bladders safe?

Tags: code-compliance, drain, drain-waste-vent

I advised a friend to use a drain bladder to clear a sink clog. Turns out there was a vent that didn't connect to the main vent stack--it just terminated inside the wall. So she put a bunch of water into the wall.

Terminating a vent inside the wall seems entirely crazy to me. Does it happen often? (60's SoCal construction) Should I have foreseen this potential problem? Or was this just bizarre bad luck?

Her landlord's father's solution to the problem scares me a little too: instead of getting the vent to the roof somehow he's making an exit under the kitchen window.

Is this a legit, code-happy (again, California) alternative to going to the roof?

Comment: Your title _Are drain-clearing bladders safe_ doesn't match the question you asked _Is this (vent) a legit, code-happy (again, California) alternative to going to the roof_, this should probably be split up into 2 separate questions to make sure you get both of your questions answered.

Comment: Did the vent have an Air Admittance Valve on it and how accessible was it?